# How to rewrite this query not to use union clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

How to rewrite this query NOT to use UNION (UNION ALL) clause:

```
SELECT
  c
FROM a
UNION
SELECT
 c
FROM b
```

expected result (recordset should be the same):

```
SELECT
  c
FROM ....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the same results as your query above, you can do this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.c, b.c) AS c
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b
    ON b.c = a.c
```

However, this will give you the same results as a UNION which is not quite the same as a UNION ALL (as duplicates will be removed). To do a UNION all, you'd need to do the same but have the join condition fail:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.c, b.c) AS c
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b
    ON 1 = 0
```

In either case, I'm not sure it would be much faster than doing it using UNION.

Comment: Bennor, it's cool! (1 = 0) - the best! performance is not an issue in this question. i could ask this question from other side: "how to avoid of using FULL (OUTER) JOIN..." i think, it's nothing to add to your answer.